# where to look for free webpage design parts like a search box

Tags: html

I am not a very skilled designer so i like to take pieces of CSS and HTML and do the logic behind them. Which are some good websites that have free layouts for things as:

- full website design
- sign in/up form
- search box
- menus
- borders
  etc.

i am spending a lot of time on some design and I know I should find some pieces like this free on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is one of the best resource to find what you are looking for
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/

Comment: this is great. do you know any other resources?